# Design pattern to use in Preview mode?

Tags: java, design-patterns, jakarta-ee

I have to provide a functionality where the people should be able to preview changes to their profiles before making them permanent. This includes the layout, the text, friends, top friends, photos, etc. The user can go into "preview mode" and review different configurations before making one live.

My question is which could be the best design patter to use?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

I guess that this is a job for the [Memento pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern)

Here, you can find some clear explanations: http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/memento